# Convert heavy HTML file to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I have an important html file to convert into a PDF file.

I use [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) to convert my HTML like this:

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($dir . '/' . $filehtml);
$mpdf = new mPDF('', '', 0, 'Helvetica', 15, 15, 50, 25, 8, 8);
$mpdf->useSubstitutions = false;
$mpdf->CSSselectMedia='mpdf';

$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'cp1252';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($file_content);
$mpdf->Output($dir . '/' . $filename, 'F');
```

It works well. *Usually*.

Problem is that **my file is pretty heavy : ~17.5Mb**, so `file_get_contents` throws me an error :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18114800 bytes)
```

---

I tried another solution : 
Instead of generate an HTML file, I tried to put `$mpdf->WriteHTML($str);` into the `foreach()` (which is used to generate my HTML file).

Problem is **execution time goes over 1hour**, which is definitly not acceptable, while generating HTML files takes me ~1.5sec (according to js `new Date().getTime();`)

---

Does anyone has a server-side solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 64M ;//maximum allotted size
```

if there is no php.ini access to you then add in .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

or add below line in your script file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your .htaccess file :
php_value memory_limit 128M